# Structure and implementation of For with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm trying to do is receive "rows" with an indefinite number of values.

Example value for `rows` (function input): `[2, 5, 43, 191]`

So I'm trying to implement a for so that I can build my array that I try to put into my query.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const SelectFilterCustomer = async (rows) => {
    let countrows = rows.length

    if (countrows == 0) {
        loadCustumers(0, customerList)
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < noGuest; i++) {
            rows[0].clacte + ","
        }

        let idcliente = rows[0].clacte
        var params = {
            database: "forecast",
            table: "customers",
            queryString: "select * from customers where clacte in ( + idcliente + ) ",
        };
        api(athenaOperation, { params: JSON.stringify(params) }).then(
            (allTodos) => {
                let _f = JSON.parse(allTodos);
                console.log(_f)
                setCustomerList(_f.Items)
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The result of `for` has to return something like this: `[2, 5, 43, 191]`, so that my query is structured like this: `select * from customers where clacte in (2, 5, 43, 191)`.

Comment: You should not build SQL queries on the client side. If you expose an endpoint that accepts SQL queries, what prevents maleficent users from using that same endpoint to submit `drop database forecast;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the values from the array, with the specified separator string a comma and a space. Example: `rows.join(', ')`

> The **join()** method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects)), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

```js
const rows = [2, 5, 43, 191]
const queryString = `select * from customers where clacte in (${rows.join(', ')})`

const params = {
  database: "forecast",
  table: "customers",
  queryString,
};

console.log(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use this approach

```
const SelectFilterCustomer = async (rows) => {
    let countrows = rows.length

    if (countrows == 0) {
        loadCustumers(0, customerList)
    } else {

        const idcliente = rows.map(rowItem => rowItem.clacte).join();
        const params = {
            database: "forecast",
            table: "customers",
            queryString: `select * from customers where clacte in ( ${idcliente} )`,
        };
        api(athenaOperation, { params: JSON.stringify(params) }).then(
            (allTodos) => {
                let _f = JSON.parse(allTodos);
                console.log(_f)
                setCustomerList(_f.Items)
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And please, avoid using "var" keyword for defining variables. Use either let or const;